# Python:For loop only works once in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, for-loop, random

I don't know why but it doesn't work.The for loop only works once and that's it

```
import string
import random
print ('Insert your words,m8')
letters = string.ascii_letters
words = input()
max_number = random.randint(6,10)
for i in range(0,max_number):
    randy = random.randint(0,25)
    title = letters[randy]
open(str(title),'w+').write(words)
```

Comment: i only want to make one file not 6-10

Comment: and instead of making  a 6-10 characters title,it makes a 1 character one.Adding it to the loop only makes it do 5 titles with still 1 character

Comment: it goes multiple times through your loop, however, you overwrite `title` (and `randy` as well) multiple times. So after your for loop `title` is still 1 letter

Comment: Try `title = ''.join([letters[random.randint(0,25)] for _ in xrange(random.randint(6,10))])`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the intent of the code is to generate a random title consisting of 6 - 10 letters and then writing the input obtained from the user to that file.If that is the case, set `title` to an empty string and then add letters to it inside the loop.

```
import string
import random
print ('Insert your words,m8')
letters = string.ascii_letters
title = ''
words = input()
max_number = random.randint(6,10)
for i in range(0,max_number):
    randy = random.randint(0,25)
    title += letters[randy]
open(str(title),'w+').write(words)
```

Answer (score 2):

Your code is

```
    import string
    import random
    print ('Insert your words,m8')
    letters = string.ascii_letters
    words = input()
    max_number = random.randint(6,10)
    for i in range(0,max_number):
        randy = random.randint(0,25)
        title = letters[randy]
    open(str(title),'w+').write(words)
```

Where the last statement  is outside for loop which will be executed after for loop finishes .

so , if you want to write one by one in word then your code should look like

```
import string
import random
print ('Insert your words,m8')
letters = string.ascii_letters
words = input()
max_number = random.randint(6,10)
for i in range(0,max_number):
    randy = random.randint(0,25)
    title = letters[randy]
    open(str(title),'w+').write(words)
```

So , loop is excuting perfectly .

Please tell what you are trying to achieve ?

Answer (score 0):

Try using a list comprehension instead of a loop:

```
import string
import random

print ('Insert your words,m8')
letters = string.ascii_letters
words = input()
title = ''.join([letters[random.randint(0, 25)] for _ in xrange(random.randint(6, 10))])
open(str(title),'w+').write(words)
```